# C++ Warning Array Subscript Has Type 'char'

Tags: c++

I require some help with code that throws a 'Warning array subscript has type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]' message.

The code in question is:-

```
static
const long hextable[] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, // 10-19
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, // 30-39
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1,
    2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1, -1, // 50-59
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, // 70-79
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 10, 11, 12, // 90-99
    13, 14, 15, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, // 110-109
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, // 130-139
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, // 150-159
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, // 170-179
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, // 190-199
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, // 210-219
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, // 230-239
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
};

long hex2long(const char* hexString)
{
    long ret = 0;
    while (*hexString && ret >= 0)
    {
        ret = (ret << 4) | hextable[*hexString++];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Now it appears that the line `ret = (ret << 4) | hextable[*hexString++];` has issues.

I am hoping someone can assist me re-structuring this code to prevent the error.

Comment: What is `hextable` and what are you trying to achieve with `*hexString++`?

Comment: I have updated question to include hextable.

Comment: change to `hextable[(uint8_t)*hexString++]`

Comment: another problem is that `ret << 4` will cause undefined behaviour after a while, depending on the string content (it is undefined to shift a 1 into the sign bit)

Comment: Thank you so much @M.M - simply changing ````hextable[(uint8_t)*hexString++]```` seems to have corrected the issue.

Comment: @M.M So do you recommend further change to the ````ret << 4````?

Comment: Yeah you probably want to change `ret >= 0` to be anything that'll detect a 1 in the top 4 bits (i.e. exit once you've filled up your output "buffer" as much as it can take)

Comment: @M.M So change to:- ````ret = (ret >= 0) | hextable[(uint8_t)*hexString++]````?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202132/discussion-between-daygle-and-m-m).

Answer (score 4):

Change `const char*` to `const unsigned char*`.

From GCC Warnings:

> -Wchar-subscripts Warn if an array subscript has type char. This is a common cause of error, as programmers often forget that this type is signed on some machines. This warning is enabled by -Wall.

The compiler doesn't want you to use negative indices for the array, so it throws a warning to let you know of this potential problem.

Comment: Changing the parameter type of `hex2long` may not be feasible.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm then you need to assign/cast `*hexString` to an `unsigned char` before using it as an array index.

Comment: Re: “ it will overflow to negative” — maybe. The behavior when a signed type overflows is undefined.

Comment: @PeteBecker there's no overflow, this answer just used incorrect terminology. Which was not even the original answerer's text, it was edited in by someone else. I've removed the offending statement (the quoted section already covers that anyway)